# SQL Query to get first two highest column values from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a query in my sql which will return the result as -

I am having a table named employee with columns name,salary,address.
The query should return the first two highest column values from the employee table.

This should be single query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the highest column is `salary`, you do this:

```
select salary from employee
order by salary desc
limit 2
```

You would do the same for any other columns, just replace the column name in the `SELECT` and in the `ORDER BY` sections.